# How to get the parent component reference

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a parent component:

```
<Parent>
<Child (click)=doSomething()></Child>
</Parent>
```

I want to have a reference to the Parent component so that I can pass it in the method, that would trigger an event that would have a parent ref.:

```
doSomething() {
// I would like to trigger the event, that would be catch elsewhere in the     app
trigger(new ClickedEvent(referenceToParent));

}
```

the event would be like:

```
class ClickedEvent {
constructor (public referenceToParent: Parent) {} 
}
```

How would I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

One of ways of interacting from child to parent component is *Parent listens events from child* https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent

So, you `doSomething` method should emit an event, which is handled by parent.

Comment: Actually, I do not want to handle it in parent component. I want to handle it elsewhere in the code :(

Comment: @JerzyGruszka why not make a service that can broadcast and register listeners for the events then?

Comment: I have that, but how to pass a reference to that particular instance?